# Не работает функция javascript, приводящая массив объектов к строке

Tags: javascript, массивы

Функция, должна привести массив объектов к строке вида:

```
Golden Branch, $1,825.65
Duncan Randall, $1,490.15
```

Но появляется следующая ошибка:

> `"Uncaught TypeError: ArrWithoutObj[i][j].join is not a function"`

Почему выбрасывается исключение?

Код:

```js
let user1 = {
  "balance": "$1,825.65",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Golden Branch",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};

let user2 = {
  "balance": "$1",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Gol Bra",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};
console.log(user1); //---
let users = [user1, user2];

console.log(users); //---

function showSalary(users, age) {
  // ваш код...
  console.log('----'); //---
  let ArrUserAgeIsTrue = users.filter(item => {if (item.age <= age) return item;})

  console.log(ArrUserAgeIsTrue); //---

  let ArrNameAndBalance = ArrUserAgeIsTrue.map(item => {
    let i = {
      name: '',
      balance: 0,
    };

    

    i.name = item.name;
    i.balance = item.balance;

    return i;
  } );

  console.log(ArrNameAndBalance); //---

  let ArrWithoutObj = ArrNameAndBalance.map(item => {
    return Object.values(item);
  })
  
  console.log(ArrWithoutObj); //---

  

  let NewStr;


  for (let i = 0; i <=  ArrWithoutObj.length; i++) {
    if (i != ArrWithoutObj.length) {
      for(let j = 0; j <= 1; j++){
        if (j == 0 ) {NewStr = ArrWithoutObj[i][j].join(', ')};
        if (j == 1) {NewStr = ArrWithoutObj[i][j].join('\r\n')};
      }
    }
    for(let j = 0; j <= 1; j++){
        if (j == 0 ) {NewStr = ArrWithoutObj[i][j].join(', ')};
        if (j == 1) {NewStr = ArrWithoutObj[i][j].join('')};

  
    }
  } 
  console.log(NewStr);
 }

showSalary(users, 30)
```

Comment: `console.log(ArrWithoutObj); //---` - ??

Comment: ну так если `ArrWithoutObj[i][j]` это объект а не массив, странно ожидать у него метод join

Comment: хотя не, проблема в опечатке: `i <=  ArrWithoutObj.length`  сравнение в циклах должно быть строгим `i <  ArrWithoutObj.length`

Comment: как-то вообще сложно сделано, можно намного проще...

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, `ArrWithoutObj` это двухмерный массив со строками, поэтому по указанным адресам строчка, у которой нет метода `join()`. Вместо этого метода и постоянной перезаписи `NewStr`, нужно применять оператор `+=`, например.

Answer (score 2):

У вас там каша из кучи ненужного кода, вот пример, как можно сделать нужное простыми функциями массива :

```js
const users = [{
  "balance": "$1,825.65",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Golden Branch",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
}, {
  "balance": "$1",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Gol Bra",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
}]

console.log(doIt(users, 30))

function doIt(users, age) {
  return users.filter(u => u.age <= age).map(u => `${u.name}, ${u.balance}`).join('\r\n')
}
```

Понимаю, не совсем ответ на вопрос, но как образовательный пример может сгодиться )

Вот исправленный ваш пример, с комментариями в нужных местах :

```js
let user1 = {
  "balance": "$1,825.65",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Golden Branch",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};

let user2 = {
  "balance": "$1",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Gol Bra",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};
console.log(user1); //---
let users = [user1, user2];

console.log(users); //---

function showSalary(users, age) {
  // ваш код...
  console.log('----'); //---
  let ArrUserAgeIsTrue = users.filter(item => {if (item.age <= age) return item;})

  console.log(ArrUserAgeIsTrue); //---

  let ArrNameAndBalance = ArrUserAgeIsTrue.map(item => {
    let i = {
      name: '',
      balance: 0,
    };

    

    i.name = item.name;
    i.balance = item.balance;

    return i;
  } );

  console.log(ArrNameAndBalance); //---

  let ArrWithoutObj = ArrNameAndBalance.map(item => {
    return Object.values(item);
  })
  
  console.log(ArrWithoutObj); //---

// присвоим пустую строку, иначе начальное значение будет undefined
  let NewStr = '';

// < вместо <=
  for (let i = 0; i <  ArrWithoutObj.length; i++) {
  // ArrWithoutObj массив массивов строк
  // ArrWithoutObj[i] массив строк, поетому джоиним его по коме и добавляем в конец перенос каретки
  // ArrWithoutObj[i][j] - строка, и как и написано в комментариях у строки нету метода join
    NewStr += ArrWithoutObj[i].join(',') + '\r\n'
  } 
  console.log(NewStr);
 }

showSalary(users, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант

```js
let user1 = {
  "balance": "$1,825.65",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Golden Branch",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};

let user2 = {
  "balance": "$1",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Gol Bra",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};

let users = [user1, user2]

let arrToStr = (arr) => {
  return users.map(user => `${user.name} ${user.balance}`).join(',')
}

console.log(arrToStr(users))
```